# Check FTP status using AppleScript

Tags: applescript, automator, ftp

I have an AppleScript Automator application that, when double-clicked, opens FTP and displays an alert confirming the same. It is working perfectly as expected. However, I am looking to make it a tad more intuitive so that it opens FTP **ONLY** if FTP isn't already open. If FTP is already open on my system, the app should close it.

So, basically I want to use the app as a toggle switch which opens or closes FTP depending on its prevailing status. The code I am currently using to open FTP and display the alert is as follows:

```
set ipaddr to IPv4 address of (get system info)
set sun to short user name of (get system info)
do shell script "sudo -s launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ftp.plist" with administrator privileges
tell application "Finder" to display alert "FTP Launched and ready for file-transfer" & character id 8233 & character id 8233 & "User Name: " & sun & character id 8233 & "IP address: " & ipaddr
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction? Is there any system variable that can be used to retrieve the FTP status? On Terminal, I could use this:

```
ftp localhost
```

And the results would tell me if it's open or closed. But how can I let AppleScript know the same?

**Additional info: Output of "*ftp localhost*" on Terminal**

Here's the result of ***ftp localhost*** when FTP is closed:

[image]

And here's the result when FTP is open:

[image]

Here, I just hit return without any input and then it gives this:

[image]

Comment: Could you include what `ftp localhost` returns exactly if it's on/off in your question?

Comment: "Open" means "FTP port is open/FTP server is running and accepting connections" I assume?

Comment: @patrix: yes you got it right.

Comment: @grgarside Please see the screenshots added to the question.

Comment: OK, it goes into interactive mode. That's impractical if you want to script it.

Comment: Exactly. Glad you see what I mean. Is there any other way its state could be retrieved via some variable or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works as a shell test, if you replace  with your target.

```
echo "QUIT" | telnet <host> ftp 2>&1 | grep  "Escape character is" > /dev/null
```

We're using hardly any complex tools, we just send a command to the server that makes it close our connection. If this works, the ftp-server is up and running. If we couldn't connect at all, this line returns `1`, else it returns `0`.

Digested to an AppleScript it's something like

```
set hostn to <host>
try
    do shell script "echo \"QUIT\" | telnet " & hostn & " ftp 2>&1 | grep  \"Escape character is\" > /dev/null"
    display dialog "Online."
on error
    display dialog "Not online."
end try
```

Comment: Try running `echo $?` afterwards.

Comment: It is not supposed to produce output, it just sets the exit status to 0 or 1. You can use `echo $?` to display it

Comment: I ran the AppleScript above and it throws this: "The action “Run AppleScript” encountered an error. Check the actionʼs properties and try running the workflow again."

Comment: Try to run it in AppleScript Editor. Might be Automator quirk.

Comment: Did you replace <host>?

Comment: Tried it both ways and this is what happens: First time, it says "Syntax error. Expected expression but found “<” with reference to the first line of the code. Then I tried running it without the "<>" and it said "the variable localhost not defined". Then I simply replaced the variable "hostn" with "localhost" and it says "not online" even when FTP is on.

Comment: Does it work in shell? `echo "QUIT" | telnet 127.0.0.1 ftp 2>&1 | grep  "Escape character is" > /dev/null`

Comment: I ran it on the command line and then ran echo $? and it returned "0"...it's the same output in either cases, both when FTP is on as well as when it's off.

Comment: Ok... I tested it only on remote servers.

Comment: @MaxRied Ok, finally it worked in Automator! Thanks a ton for your patience. I just replaced localhost with the IP (127.0.0.1) and it went through. Not sure why though but it's all good. Thanks again. :)

Comment: You could also use `netstat -a | grep .ftp | grep -q LISTEN` instead of `telnet`.